# Non-Blocking CompleteableFuture that Executes before Program Exits

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I'm executing an application (`static void main(String[] args)` that asynchronously makes `POST` requests to an endpoint in a particular cadence.  Because of the number of requests and the lengthy run time of the application, it's not feasible to hold the futures in a list and then process them after-the-fact.

So, I've added a `thenAcceptAsync` call that simply logs the responses as they come in.  However, especially for shorter test runs, the program will complete and exit before some of the responses return.

How can I ensure that all responses are logged before the program finishes?

```
public void replayScripts() {
    final String applicationId = getSparkApplicationId();
    LOGGER.debug("applicationId: {}", applicationId);

    final long scriptsToSubmit = this.config.getMaxScripts() == null ? this.config.getScripts().size()
            : this.config.getMaxScripts().intValue();
    long maxWaitTimeMillis = 0L;
    long actualWaitTimeMillis = 0L;

    for (int i = 0; i < scriptsToSubmit; i++) {
        LOGGER.info("submitting script #{} of {}", i + 1, scriptsToSubmit);

        this.dao.submitScript(this.config.getScripts().get(i).getRawScript())
                .thenAcceptAsync(this::logResponse);

        if (i + 1 < this.config.getScripts().size()) {
            final long millisWait = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(
                    Duration.between(this.config.getScripts().get(i).getSubmissionTime(),
                            this.config.getScripts().get(i + 1).getSubmissionTime()).get(ChronoUnit.NANOS),
                    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

            maxWaitTimeMillis += millisWait;
            actualWaitTimeMillis += sleep(millisWait, applicationId);

            if (this.config.getClearCache()) {
                this.dao.clearCache();
            }
        }
    }

    LOGGER.info("max wait time: {}s", maxWaitTimeMillis / 1000.0);
    LOGGER.info("actual wait time: {}s", actualWaitTimeMillis / 1000.0);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** the solution

Using @irahavoi's suggestion, I went with the counter solution for the time being, adding this snippet, which uses an `AtomicInteger` class member to keep track of the number of logged responses:

```
    while (this.config.isLogResponses() && this.loggedResponsesCounter.get() < scriptsToSubmit) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("sleeping for one second to allow all responses to be logged");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("An exception occurred while attempting to wait for all responses to be logged", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Because of the number of requests and the lengthy run time of the application, it's not feasible to hold the futures in a list and then process them after-the-fact" 
But why? 
I do not see any problem with using smth like this in your main method:

CompletableFuture.allOf(yourListOfLogPipelineResponses).join();

This way you will ensure that your program won't exit before all responses are logged.

Comment: i'm replaying days and weeks worth of scripts for testing, easily totaling in the hundreds of thousands. if i hold too many in memory, i get oom exceptions.  what you suggested is what i had been doing, and while it worked for smaller tests, it quickly exhausted the available memory for any sizable run.

Comment: Ah, I see.. But you do know the number of requests (scriptsToSubmit). You could have a counter for received responses (each time a response comes in, it's incremented). and periodically check it in your main thread: if the counter's value equals scriptsToSubmit then it's ok to exit.

Comment: oof, yea, that would work...not terribly elegant, which is beside the point i suppose, but i figured there would be some completablefuture mechanism or code design change i could make to accomplish this

Comment: don't know any elegant solution for this, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options to solve this (neither is super elegant):

1. Split your requests in batches (each batch is 1k requests, for example). And process each batch separately. This way you'll be able to use this without the risk of OOM:

   CompletableFuture.allOf(aBatchOfLogPipelineResponses).join();
2. As mentioned in the comment above, you could have a counter for received responses (each time a response comes in, it's incremented). and periodically check it in your main thread: if the counter's value equals scriptsToSubmit then it's ok to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that might be cleaner is to shutdown your [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and wait for its termination.

I would assume that you already use a customized `ExecutorService` in your DAO since the common pool used by default by `CompletableFuture` is not suitable for IO tasks. Otherwise, you should look into the factory methods in [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

So, once you have submitted all your tasks, you should call [`ExecutorService.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()), followed by [`awaitTermination()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), on the main thread.

This will wait for all tasks (including queued ones) to finish execution.